# Add JQuery Reference in Office Web AddIn

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

How do i Add JQuery Reference in Office Web AddIn.

I have tried putting them in

- Added reference in TaskPane.html
- Added direct reference from internet in Taskpane.html
- Tried following script in Taskpane.js

  function addJQuery()
      {
          var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
          var scriptjQuery = document.createElement('script');
          scriptjQuery.type = 'text/javascript';
          scriptjQuery.id = 'jQuery'
          scriptjQuery.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js';
          var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          head.insertBefore(scriptjQuery, script);
      }

None of the above option is working. and all of them gives $ is undefined error.

Comment: Adding reference in Taskpane.html is right way for this. There might be issue with the sequence in which you are loading scripts

Comment: will it be possible for you to share some code or reference.  some how its not working out for me. This is very crucial for me as i need to connect to external Service. Because it seems there is no way i can access the Project Custom Fields directly via Office.js API.

Comment: Could you share a code snippet of the Taskpane.html where you're including the scripts? That will make it easier to figure out the root cause.

Here is a sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo/blob/master/InsertTextPane/InsertText.html

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your html :

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```